# MATLAB remove noise

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis

I am in trouble with my study, could you please help me.
I have a set of data containing information about the signal that come from a preamplifier of the radiation detector system. After radiation interacts with the material of det., electrons and holes are created, then they will be charged through a CR high-pass filter. I think you will easy to understand if you take a look at the attached picture. The time increment is 2e-8 seconds. 
SO, MY QUESTIONS IS: By using MATLAB, how to remove the noise from the real signal ( the blue one) to make it become the signal like the red one. And how to find exactly the time interval of the yellow one. 
Thank you very much for your concern. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me.
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? Which filter did you test? And why didn't it work?

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=filter+noise+from+signal

Comment: Do you have of model for your decaying part? Some exponential? Depending on the priori information you have: noise statistics, signal models, different answers can be given